# I have some problem with passive form of verbs, and actually with に particle in it

Tags: grammar, particle-に, passive-voice

So, I have this:

> 父**に**犬を追いかけられています。

Is it correct? And what does that に particle mean?

Comment: Could you tell us what you want to say in English?

Comment: So, in this case the sentence was translated as: the dog is being chased by my father. But I was confused because of the に particle which shows the passive form.

Comment: "the dog is being chased by my father." would be「犬が父に追いかけられています。」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I have had a misunderstanding as reported by chocolate in the comments, so I have corrected myself.

The に particle here shows the agent (the one who does the action). 犬を追いかける is "to run after a dog".

So 「父**に**犬を追いかけられています。」 is "The dog is run after **by** my father."

Comment: So, in this case に shows that the father orders someone (the person omitted) to run after the dog. 
In the case I want to say "father is chasing after the dog", do I have to use は particle?
P.s.: thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: "私 has to run after the dog because his/her father told him/her so" -> それだと「父に犬を追いかけ**させ**られています。」になりますよね・・

Comment: @BeatriceJitariu "In the case I want to say 'father is chasing after the dog'." >> "Father is chasing the dog" is 「父が犬を追いかけています。」(active voice). The passive voice would be "The dog is being chased by Father"「犬が父に追いかけられています。」

Comment: Doesn't that mean that the dog is being given higher precedence than the father? I thought you would have to say "Father ran after the dog" in Japanese because otherwise you are making a dog more important than a human.

Comment: @user3856370 Yes, here the dog is more important than the father. That's the role of the passive voice: to change the focus. At least, that's how I view it.

Answer (score 2):

I think 父が犬に追いかけられています is correct.

In the case of 父に犬を追いかけられています,
if I must say, it means 'My dog gets chased by my father.'

に is a postpositional particle for an object.

For example:

> 父に犬を[呼]{よ}んでもらいます。
>   I have my father call a dog.

Comment: Oh, finally I got it. So with particle に: the dog-object which suffers and subject, (my)father-agent. And with が: father-subject and agent, dog- object which suffers. Thank you.